# Why doesn't this code need clearerr for feof?

Tags: c, debugging, stdin, eof, feof

Every stream has an "end-of-file (EOF) flag".
The flag is only cleared if you call the clearerr function on the stream.
feof(p) function returns the current state of this EOF flag.

https://ibb.co/zGNcCZp

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    int i=0;
    int arr[100];
    while(1){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        if(feof(stdin)){
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        printf("%d ",arr[j]);
    }
    i=0;
    printf("\n");
    while(1){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        if(feof(stdin)){
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        printf("%d ",arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Images of code or error messages are problematic for a number of reasons. Please review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors and [edit] your question to replace the screen shot with text.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't this code need clearerr for feof?

You are using [scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

You could read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), then a C draft standard e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better and look into [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website.

That `scanf` function returns an interesting item count.

On failure, it also sets the [feof](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/feof.3.html) flag.

You don't need any initial `clearerr` because the implicit `fopen` - or the implicit initialization - of `stdin` (done in [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) before calling `main`; see also [fdopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3.html)) is either calling it or doing the equivalent.

**If you use a [GNU/Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) system, all of `crt0`, [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/), and [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) are open source or [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), and *you* are allowed to download, study and even *improve* their source code**.

See of course [Linux From Scratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/). It documents how to compile all that from source code. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65751539/841108) related answer and consider installing [Debian](https://debian.org/) on your laptop.

Comment: the implicit fopen - or the implicit initialization - of stdin  is either calling it or doing the equivalent. What do you mean?